# JVM never terminates after annotation processing; must clean before every build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, annotations

I've added an annotation processor to my Android project. It runs without error and produces the expected result. However, I have two issues with it that are slowing down my development.

The first is that every time I make the project I have to clean first, or I get

```
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Error reading configuration file
```

The second is that when I attempt to clean, I get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':processor:clean'.
Unable to delete file: D:\Users\Tony\AndroidProjects\Minder\processor\build\libs\processor.jar
```

This appears to be because the JVM in which the annotation processor runs never terminates. If I go into the task manager (working on Windows) and close the "Java Platform SE binary" process, I am able to clean without error. After I clean, everything runs fine.

Here is my gradle.build for my app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "us.bridgeses.minder"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 22
    versionName "2.0-beta"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':processor')
compile project(':annotations')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.3'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
    exclude group: 'junit'  // junit:junit-dep conflicts with junit:unit
}
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
}
```

Comment: I have this problem too. You find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

As solution for finished annotation processor you can use `.jar` file of `compiler` instead of the whole project. Using jar will enable you to clean project without problems. Just add your `compiler.jar` to libs folder and replace `compile project(':processor')` with `apt files('libs/compiler.jar')`.

But i don't find solution to modify `compiler` project and test changes without `clean` and terminating "Java Platform SE binary" process